# Python: If input is in a written file not working

Tags: python, file, input

So this is a program that I am writing. The aim is to have an input and the program check to see if that input is in the file. However I am not sure how to go about doing this. This is what I have so far.

```
def writefile():
    myfile = open("problems.txt", "w")
    myfile.write("display blank smashed cracked")
    myfile.write("display")
    myfile.write("blank")
    myfile.write("smashed")
    myfile.write("cracked")

    myfile.close()

writefile()

print("=======This is a mobile phone troubleshooting assistant system.=======")

def readfile():
    print("This is where we will establish your issue.")
    input1 = input("What is your problem?")
    myfile = open("problems.txt")
    list1=myfile.readlines()
    if input1 in list1:
        print("ISSUE FOUND")

readfile()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use raw_input instead of input, also check for each line (for line in list1)

```
def writefile():
    myfile = open("problems.txt", "w")
    myfile.write("display blank smashed cracked")
    myfile.write("display")
    myfile.write("blank")
    myfile.write("smashed")
    myfile.write("cracked")

    myfile.close()

writefile()

print("=======This is a mobile phone troubleshooting assistant system.=======")

def readfile():
    print("This is where we will establish your issue.")
    input1 = raw_input("What is your problem?")
    myfile = open("problems.txt")
    list1=myfile.readlines()
    for line in list1:
        if input1 in line:
            print("ISSUE FOUND")

readfile()
```